# Как уведомлять об новых сообщениях? php

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

В данный момент, я пишу чатик, который парсится из логов. Сделано все на php+ajax. Все работает как задумано, но вот как сделать уведомление об новых сообщениях, я так и не додумался. Я полагаю нужно ставить флаги внутри сообщений которые парсятся, но из-за того что страница обновляется раз в секунду, у файлов сбрасываются флаги на первоначальные. Куда мне копать в такой ситуации?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Kaboom 2.0 Чат</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mode() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'global.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#gchatloader').html(data);
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'local.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#lchatloader').html(data);
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'private.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#pchatloader').html(data);

                    }
                });
            };
            setInterval(mode, 1000);
        </script>
        <script>
            var i = 0;

            function func() {
                $("body").mouseover(function() {
                    i = 1;
                });
                $("body").mouseout(function() {
                    i = 2;
                });
                if (i != 1) {
                    $("#pchatloader").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
                    $("#gchatloader").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
                    $("#lchatloader").scrollTop(99999999999999999999);
                }
            }
            setInterval(func, 1000);
        </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
        <label for="tab1" title="Вкладка 1">Общий чат</label>

        <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
        <label for="tab2" title="Вкладка 2">Локальный чат</label>

        <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
        <label for="tab3" title="Вкладка 3">Личные сообщения</label>

        <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
        <label for="tab4" title="Вкладка 4">Запаска</label>

        <section id="content-tab1">
            <div id="gchatloader"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="content-tab2">
            <div id="lchatloader"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="content-tab3">
            <div id="pchatloader"></div>
        </section>
        <section id="content-tab4">
            <div id="server"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В результате парса, получается страница вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предполагаю что можно как-то считать количество сообщений. И если с прошлого подсчета, оно увеличилось на 1, то значит есть новое сообщение. Только опять же не знаю как это написать.

Comment: не используйте ajax внутри setInterval , лучше через рекурсию чем так

Comment: я думаю для чата вам стоит посмотреть в сторону такой технологии как `WebSocket`

Comment: Там не совсем чатик, я просто вывожу все это в веб морду.
Сами функции чата не нужны по сути.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, сделал как примерно и думал. При парсинге текста, добавил им class и просто считал их количество. А при нажатии на вкладку, запоминал число в скрытый див. При автоповторе скрипта, он сравнит количество сообщений с числом из дива. Все собственно просто. (особенно когда раздуплился =))

```js
var cnt, i;

function func1() {
    var div = document.querySelectorAll('lcr'); // Получаем список все блоков документа
    cnt = div.length; // Считаем количество блок
    //alert(cnt); // Выводи на экран результат
    var label = document.getElementById('mig_label');
    var i = document.getElementById('lcdcalc').innerHTML;
    if (i < cnt) {
        label.style.color = "#E81700";
        setTimeout(function() {}, 5000);
    }
}

function lcd() {
    var div = document.querySelectorAll('lcr'); // Получаем список все блоков документа
    cnt = div.length; // Считаем количество блок
    var label = document.getElementById('mig_label');
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('lcdcalc'),
    SummSumm = cnt;
    SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
    SummDok.style.display = "none";
    label.style.color = "#aaaaaa";
}
setInterval(func1, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="lcdcalc"></div>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2" title="Вкладка 2"><a id='mig_label' onclick="lcd();" target="blank">Локальный чат</a></label>
```